# Basic HTML Grocery Website?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web

My teacher's making us make a grocery website. I've never done an HTML assignmet before, never even tried it but now it's my summative. He told us we had to make a grocery website, with at least 50 items. I got the items, and they're in 8 categories, each one having 6 for now (like fruits, dairy etc)

When you click on a product, you should be directed to another page that shows a picture of the item, a description, and it's producer. To cut some work, should I use Java script to make arrays within arrays to hold all that information for each product so that when I click the product, a new page comes up automatically with all the information (even if all the pages will have different info?) Or will I have to program all 50 pages?! I'm new to programming but I want to head the most efficient way? Java script is required, and I'm still in the planning stages and I can't think of anything effective?

Comment: Haha. why do you need to create 50 pages for each product? Just create one page for product details and use the product ID to load the details of the product and post it into the page. *- "you made my day"*.

Comment: You mean I need to make a function for each item?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a main page, say `index.html`, with links such as `product.html?item=1` and `product.html?item=2`.

Then, on the product page, you can use javascript to capture the item value and display the product information from an array.